# Show row details on popup as montser CRUD for laravel backpack demo

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to know how to show or achieve the row details of CRUD on the modal pop-up shown in the demo instance of Laravel backpack Monster CRUD.

I want a tip so that I start implementing this feature.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

thats is the "Detail Row" feature, you can find information about it in [documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-operation-list-entries#details-row-1)

Basically you need to enable

```
CRUD::enableDetailsRow();
```

and create a view for this detail overwriting "showDetailsRow($id)" method.

Cheers.